# How to fill selectonemenu JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I want to fill an selectonemenu from my data base , but always the list is empty
this is my code:

```
public ArrayList<String> FindListKpi(Integer userid)
 {
  ArrayList<String> usrpr=new ArrayList<String>();
  try{

        EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
        entr.begin();

        javax.persistence.Query multipleSelect= em.createQuery("select k.kpiName FROM ProfilUser p, Kpi k, AssociationKpiProfil a WHERE p= a.profilUser and a.kpi=k and  p.profilUserId= :w" );
   multipleSelect.setParameter("w", userid);
   /* to tranform list to an arraylist*/
   List usrpro =  new LinkedList();
   usrpro= multipleSelect.getResultList();
   usrpr = new ArrayList(usrpro);

       entr.commit(); 
       System.out.println("listttttttttttttttttttttttt"+usrpr.toString());
  return usrpr;
      }
      catch (Exception e )
      {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("error");
      }
      finally {
        em.close();
    } 

  return usrpr;

 }
```

My function that fill selectbox:

```
public List<SelectItem> getMyListKPIs()  {
FindKpi fkpi =new FindKpi();

if (MyListKPI == null) {
MyListKPI = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

for (String val : fkpi.FindListKpi(iduser)) {
MyListKPI.add(new SelectItem(val));
}
}
 return MyListKPI;
}
```

the result:
listttttttttttttttttttttttt[]

I have tested my method "FindListKpi" and it works fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("list"+ kpilist.FindListKpi(1));
}
```

The result:

```
list [Number Of Closed issues, Number Of Opened issues]
```

So the problem in the method getMyListKPIs ,in fact the error is exactly at the proprity "iduser" ,this proprity I have passed it's value from another bean :

```
 <managed-bean>
 <managed-bean-name>ToolsKPI</managed-bean-name> 
 <managed-bean-class>DAOKPI.ToolsKPI</managed-bean-class>
 <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope> 
 <managed-property>
<property-name>iduser</property-name>
<property-class>java.lang.Integer</property-class>
<value>#{BeanTools.iduser}</value>
</managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello I have resolved the problem the error was at the file faces-config ,my managed-proprity was wrong,in fact to hold the value of an attribute the configuration is:

iduser
    java.lang.Integer
    #{BeanTools.iduser}